# Using expect to emulate user input

Tags: bash, shell, expect

I am attempting to answer `y` in a `[y/N]` prompt during a scripted install on the command line (`-y` is not an option).

So far I have the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
expect << EOF 
dasht-docsets-install expressjs
expect "[y/N]"
send "y"
EOF
```

But that gives the following output:

```
invalid command name "dasht-docsets-install"
    while executing
"dasht-docsets-install expressjs"
```

I have mutiple docsets to install and only one can be installed at a time, i.e I can not go `dasht-docsets-install expressjs vuejs` etc...so ideally I would like to create a bash function that can be handed a `docset` like so:

```
doc_install expressjs
```

This would take care of handling the input.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try this: `echo y | dasht-docsets-install expressjs`

Comment: Does not seem to work.

Comment: While the accepted answer works for your specific case, your issue was due because you called your function directly inside expect. The expect will thus interprete `dasht-docsets-install` as an expect keyword (which doesnt exist and raises the error). You should have written `spawn dasht-docsets-install expressjs` to make it work. Also, to validate your send, you'd need to write `send "y\r"`

Comment: @OtisWright : *dasht-docsets-install* is not a valid Tcl command. You would have to use `spawn` to submit the command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
dasht-docsets-install -f expressjs

# `-f`, `--force`
#   Forces the operation by overriding the interactive confirmation prompt.
```

Source: [github repo](https://github.com/sunaku/dasht/blob/master/bin/dasht-docsets-install).

Comment: Thank you, can't believe I missed that.